# In computer science, what is NOT a formal language?

Tags: math, compiler-construction, computer-science

On the wikipedia https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Formal_language, I found the definition of a formal language:

> In mathematics, computer science, and linguistics, a formal language
>   is a set of strings of symbols that may be constrained by rules that
>   are specific to it.

This looks quite abstract to me. And I can't image any language which doesn't fit to this definition. Does anyone have ideas about what a **informal language** looks like and how it doesn't fit the definition?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming within the limits of the application of that term here on SO.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, that's too bad because in my opinion there is a major shortage of interesting questions on SO lately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me get to your question first. A good non-example of a formal language are the *natural* languages.  English and Slovene are examples. So are Tagalog and Tarifit Berber. Unfortunately linguists don't seem to have a definition of natural language that all would agree upon.

Noam Chomsky famously tried to model natural language using context-free gammars in his 1956 paper [*Three Models for the Description of Language*](https://chomsky.info/wp-content/uploads/195609-.pdf). He invented (or discovered, if you prefer) them in that paper; although he didn't called them that; while they weren't useful to model the English language, they revolutionized computer science.

Formally, a formal language is just a set of strings over a finite alphabet. That's it.

Examples include all valid C programs, all valid HTML files, all valid XML files, all strings of "balanced" parentheses (e.g. `(), ()(), ((()))()(()), ...`), the set (codes under some encoding) of all deterministic Turing machines that always halt, the set of all simple graphs that can be colored with `k`-colors (actually their codes under some encoding), the set of all binary strings that end and begin with a `1`, etc.

Some are easy to recognize using regex (or, equivalently, DFA); some are impossible to recognize using DFA's, but can be recognized using PDA (or, equivalently, can be described with a context-free grammar); other's don't admit such a description, but can be recognized by a Turing machine; some aren't recognizable even by a Turing machine (called uncomputable).

This is why the definition is so useful. Many things we encounter in CS evey day can be cast in terms of formal languages.

For a good introduction to the subject, I highly recommend the superb book *Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation* by Hopcroft et al.

Answer (score 1):

English isn't a formal language. It's not just a set of strings; it has a spoken form, and evolution over time, and dialects, and all sorts of other things a formal language doesn't have. A formal language couldn't gain the word "email" from one decade to the next.

Answer (score 0):

A language is a set of sequences made up from given symbols. It can be either finite or infinite (the set of English sentences is infinite even though there are sentences, eg excessively long, which can not be comprehended even by a native speaker). If it is finite then any description of it is a formal definition.

If the language is infinite, say the language of arithmetic expressions involving numbers, two binary operators '+', '*' and variables then you can't possibly list all strings which belong to the language, but sometimes (see blazs's comment below) you can give a finite description as a set of rules.

E := NUM | v | E '+' E | E '*' E

(where NUM is a sequence of digits, v is a variable) is a finite description of an infinite set. That's what makes it formal.

The various other aspects like speech or the evolution of the language are different issues. Those can also be formalised.

Comment: You can't awlays describe a formal language using context-free grammars... you sometimes need more powerful machinery.

Comment: I never said that the left hand side of the production system must be a single symbol. It can even be epsilon if you wish.

Comment: Ok, let `T` be the set of all deterministic Turing machines that always halt after a finite number of steps (on every input). Give me a description. I'll wait. :)

Comment: When you say you'll wait do you mean you aren't even going to eat :)? I added 'sometimes' to the statement on formalisability to reflect that not all sets are amenable.